# CSS background color show another color

Tags: html, css

I have a tooltip.

tooltip background color is #FFFFFF (white).

[image]

If you see above image in that tooltip black line also showing. How to remove black line in tooltip using css.

These is the CSS i am using.

```
.tipsy-inner {

     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     color: black;
     height:30px ! important;
     max-width: 400px ! important;
     padding: 1px 12px -3px 0px ! important;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid black !important;
     border-radius: 8px;
     font-family: Open Sans !important;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Please show all relevant CSS code

Comment: Post the source code please.

Comment: which blackline are you talking about? we cannot help without a bit more details (like code ...^^) Post simplified example here -> http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i think that is opacity problem..

Comment: In rounded rectangle box there is a black line. I want how to remove that line.

Comment: Are you talking about the border that is black?

Comment: @divy3993 no i am talking inside rectangle border..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try giving in your CSS:

```
.tipsy { opacity: 1 !important; }
```

Comment: Adding !important is poor form. Better to properly override the css that is causing the opacity.

Comment: Dear Bill, go to the problem first then answer. problem is not with `.tipsy-inner`. I guess panabaka is not aware about this. So setting bg and opacity on inner would not help in any way. I checked tipsy plugin .. which is giving inline styling onhover. so either we have to change the JS or we need to add !important to override that.. i hope m cleared enough.. rest is your decision to mark as downvote the answer. :) happy coding.

Comment: @panabakavenkatesh: dont forget to mark as answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The "black line" is a border of an element, so remove the

```
border: 1px solid black !important;
```

line from your css style.

Answer (score -1):

It appears the opacity is not 100%, you could try:

> background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

Or

> background-color: white; opacity: 1;

Comment: wrong.  as changing format of giving bg color will not increase the opacity in any manner.

Comment: @panabakavenkatesh : issue is opacity only.. check in firebug if parent container is having opacity.

Comment: @Era No parent container doesn't have opacity.

Comment: try the answer I gave.

Comment: If you'll note I was suggesting rgba which includes "alpha"  Or in the second line I included opacity:1;